# Insert literal text that begins with = sign

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I would like to add text that begins with an equal sign in a cell but I get the following error:

> `#NAME?`

**Question:**

How can I set a cell's text to a string that begins with the `=` sign?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Google Sheets, as in some other spreadsheet apps, typing a single apostrophe at the beginning of your entry will prevent the software parsing your input.

Type `'=Hello` and `=Hello` will appear in the cell.

Answer (score 2):

One more option would be to quote it whole like

```
="=Hello"
```

or if it's joint of something then:

```
="="&SUM(A1+B1)
```

and already mentioned:

```
'=Hello
```